# Should REST based modules/controllers be split by resource or action/functionality

Tags: javascript, rest, model-view-controller, nestjs, web-development-server

I have a use case that looks like this:

API1: Fetch all books in the US belonging to John: `GET Request` on `/country/us/person/john/books`

API2: Fetch all books belonging to john in all countries: `GET Request` on `/person/john/books`

API3: Fetch all books in all countries: `GET Request` on `/country/books`

I want to build a rest server using `NestJS` (but that's not too relevant to this question) which uses the concepts of `modules` to organize `controllers`.

In this example should I have a:

- `module` called `books` with 1 `controller` handing 3 routes. Or,
- 2 `modules`, `booksByCountry` and `booksByPerson`

Is there a recommended way to think about this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends about how you want to setup your API semantically.
To me, according to your use cases and resources access, since you want to retrieve books resources by person and/or by country, I'd go for something like this:

### First way of thinking:

*API1: Fetch all books in the US belonging to John:*
GET Request on `/books/person/{personName}/country/{countryName}`

*API2: Fetch all books belonging to john in all countries:*
GET Request on `/books/person/{personName}`

*API3: Fetch all books in all countries:*
GET Request on `/books`

### Another way of thinking about it:

*API1: Fetch all books in the US belonging to John:*
GET Request on `/persons/{personName}/books?country={countryName}`

*API2: Fetch all books belonging to john in all countries:*
GET Request on `/persons/{personName}/books?country=all` (or `/persons/{personName}/books` if you don't want to handle an **all** query param value)

*API3: Fetch all books in all countries:*
GET Request on `/books`

### Conclusion:

It all depends on the semantic coherence of you URIs and the way you want to handle your path and query parameters. 
Whether you'd like to expose publicly your API or for internal use only, make it easy and coherent the way you expose your resources so your consumers are not lost when reading the docs and using your API.

Let me know if it helps, also comments and other POVs are welcomed about this subject !